# Array of union with members of different size

Tags: c, arrays, unions

I have a somewhat unusual question. Since I am reverse engineering code the data structure I use (which is terrible by the way) can not be changed. First of all this is the struct which causes my trouble right now:

```
typedef struct {
    build_field build;
    u8 field_1;
    u8 level;
    u8 field_3;
    u16 species;
    union{
        struct {
            u16 field_6;
        } default_item_default_attacks;
        struct {
            u16 moves[4];
            u16 field_E;
        } default_item_custom_attacks;
        struct {
            u16 item;
        } custom_item_default_attacks;
        struct {
            u16 item;
            u16 moves[4];
        } custom_item_custom_attacks;
    } item_and_moves;
} trainer_pokemon;
```

As you can see the size of the struct `trainer_pokemon` varies depending on which uninion member I use to instanciate. The problem is that I need to instanciate several `trainer_pokemon[]`. As expected my C-Compiler just expands the size of each member of this array to the maximum (as if I always used the union member `custom_item_custom_attacks` for instanciating). However the game I am reverse engineering expects the array's members to match the size of the union used. That may sound somewhat confusing, so I will provide a more concrete example:

```
trainer_pokemon[] t = {
                {
                        0x0, //build
                        0x0, //ability bit
                        false, //hidden ability
                        false, //shiny
                },
                0x0, //field_1
                8, //Level
                0, //field_3
                POKEMON_LICHTEL, {
                        .default_item_default_attacks = {
                                0x0, //field_6,
                        }
                }
        },
        {
                {
                        0x0, //build
                        0x0, //ability bit
                        false, //hidden ability
                        false, //shiny
                },
                0x0, //field_1
                6, //Level
                0, //field_3
                POKEMON_TRAUMATO,
                {
                        .default_item_default_attacks = {
                                0x0, //field_6,
                        }
                }
        }
};
```

As you can see 8 Bytes per element of this array would be sufficient to instanciate this array (total size 16 bytes). However each member is zero-filled up to the size of 16 bytes (total size of 32 bytes) since the compiler just assumes that i instanciated with `custom_item_custom_attacks` which would need an additional amount of 8 bytes. The problem is that the game engine expects the structure to fit the minimum size (in this case 8 bytes).
How do I best remodell or fix this issue? Please also note that inside one array all members are of the same size and must be instanciated with the same union member.

Comment: `sizeof(trainer_pokemon)` will be increased by the biggest element in your union. If this is what you meant.

Comment: And thats what I want to prevent. I think i have to remodell my data structure but how to do so? Is there a better way?

Comment: What if you use pointers in side structure and then init your data outside this variable? So your structure just holds pointer to somewhere. If it is non-null, you know that it has valid value, otherwise you ignore it.

Comment: How is `build_field` defined?

Comment: "The problem is that the game engine expects the structure to fit the minimum size" How is this expectation expressed in engine's code? Maybe the engine is doing something crazy, but maybe you misunderstand something about the way the engine runs.

Comment: I can not change the data structure, that is the problem. The bytewise structure is already predefined by the game engine. That means i can not insert a random pointer somewhere. I need to model it properly into c code tho.

The definition of build_field is kind of irrelevant, it provides an 8-bit value but since all union types share it it is not what causes the problems.

Also the engine's code is assembly, since I am reverse engineering, I have no clue how the developers modelled this...

Comment: A variable size struct is not possible. For the compiler sizeof(struct) is a constant. If there is a union inside, the largest size will be used.

Comment: Can't you just model it differently from how the original does it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're after is some kind of polymorphism(sp?). Instead of using unions, you can define your structures something like this

```
struct base_type
  {
  int type;
  };

struct type_a
  {
  struct base_type base;
  long some_value;
  };

struct type_b
  {
  struct base_type base;
  char tiny_value;
  };

struct base_type *my_type_a=malloc(sizeof(struct type_a));
my_type_a.type=1;
struct base_type *my_type_b=malloc(sizeof(struct type_b));
my_type_b.type=2;
struct type_a *a=(struct type_a *) my_type_a;
```

Both the "type" structs share the same common attributes as provided by the base_type struct, but they can be of different sizes as required. You just need to make sure that when allocating the memory you populate the right values to be able to correctly identify which actual struct it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several structs and a base struct:

```
typedef struct {
    build_field build;
    u8 field_1;
    u8 level;
    u8 field_3;
    u16 species;
} trainer_pokemon_base;

typedef struct {
    build_field build;
    u8 field_1;
    u8 level;
    u8 field_3;
    u16 species;

    u16 field_6;
} trainer_pokemon_did;

typedef struct {
    build_field build;
    u8 field_1;
    u8 level;
    u8 field_3;
    u16 species;

    u16 moves[4];
    u16 field_E;
} trainer_pokemon_dic;

typedef struct {
    build_field build;
    u8 field_1;
    u8 level;
    u8 field_3;
    u16 species;

    u16 item;
} trainer_pokemon_cid;

typedef struct {
    build_field build;
    u8 field_1;
    u8 level;
    u8 field_3;
    u16 species;

    u16 item;
    u16 moves[4];
} trainer_pokemon_cic;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use several different struct types:

```
typedef struct {
    build_field build;
    u8 field_1;
    u8 level;
    u8 field_3;
    u16 species;
} trainer_base;

typedef struct {
    trainer_base b;
    u16 field_6;
} trainer_pokemon_default_item_default_attacks;

typedef struct {
    trainer_base b;
    u16 moves[4];
    u16 field_E;
} trainer_pokemon_default_item_custom_attacks;

typedef struct {
    trainer_base b;
    u16 item;
} trainer_pokemon_custom_item_default_attacks;

typedef struct {
    trainer_base b;
    u16 item;
    u16 moves[4];
} trainer_pokemon_custom_item_custom_attacks;
```

You could also define a custom type that can "be" any type and where you can access the extra fields as `trainer->extra_field[i]`:

```
typedef struct {
    trainer_base b;
    u16 extra_field[0];
} trainer_pokemon;
```

You would use the custom type like this:

```
trainer_pokemon *trainer = malloc(sizeof(trainer_pokemon_default_item_custom_attacks));
trainer->extra_field[2]; // This would access moves[2].
trainer->extra_field[4]; // This would access field_E.
```

Note: You need to take special care when using `sizeof` and array arithmetic. You always need to use the correct specific type.

Note: **Very important!** If you use the custom type and the other types mixed, then you need to be very aware of the strict aliasing rule and its implications. If you don't know the strict aliasing rule well you should stick to using the specific types.